# Cloudformation template error "The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations

Tags: templates, resources, aws-cloudformation

```
---
Parameters:
  SSHKey:
    Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
    Description: Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the instance
Resources:
  MyInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-1a
      ImageId: ami-00eb20669e0990cb4
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      SubnetId: subnet-082bbf8546527d556
      KeyName: !Ref SSHKey
      SecurityGroups:
        - !Ref SSHSecurityGroup
      # we install our web server with user data
      UserData: 
        Fn::Base64: |
          #!/bin/bash -xe
          yum update -y
          yum install -y httpd
          systemctl start httpd
          systemctl enable httpd
          echo "Hello World from user data" > /var/www/html/index.html

  # our EC2 security group
  SSHSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: SSH and HTTP
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - CidrIp: 10.20.20.0/24
        FromPort: 22
        IpProtocol: tcp
        ToPort: 22
      - CidrIp: 10.20.20.0/24
        FromPort: 80
        IpProtocol: tcp
        ToPort: 80
```

Comment: Corrected source intenting for code parts.

Comment: Which region are you deploying your CloudFormation stack in? `t2` is not available in newer regions like `eu-north-1`, `ap-east-1`, `me-south-1`, and `us-gov-east-1`

Comment: I'm Trying to deploy it in us-east-1

Comment: Now I'm getting the new error "Parameter groupname cannot be used with the parameter subnet"